# Parser Error in angular

Tags: angular, ngfor

```
 <agm-marker  *ngFor="let k of marker|keyconductores" 
                  [latitude]="{{marker[k].lat}}" 
                  [longitude]="{{marker[k].lng}}" >
  </agm-marker>
```

ERROR
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{marker[k].lat}}] in ng:///AppModule/MapaComponent.html@3:18 ("lng">

Comment: you cannot add {{}} sign in [latitude] attribute of <agm-maker> just use [latitude]="k.clat" as {{conductores[k].clat}} is use only in view to show it's value

Comment: can you post what your pipe keyconductores

Answer (score 0):

No need to use curly brackets when binding values to angular input parameters

```
<agm-marker  *ngFor="let item of conductores|keyconductores" 
                  [latitude]="item.clat" 
                  [longitude]="item.clng" >
  </agm-marker>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, for example: <button _ngcontent-c1="" name="marker[k].name">home</button>, <button _ngcontent-c1="" name="marker[k].name">{{marker[k].name}}</button> ,
if I remove brackets it is printed literal

Comment: create a sample demo